# Can I speak of fighting for a discussion where no insult, or swearing is involved?

Tags: word-choice

Can I speak of fighting for a discussion where nobody is swearing, saying insults, or using violence?

Imagine two people (A and B) are talking, and A asks B what she meant when she said something. As result, B reminds A what he said in a different, unrelated situation, and A says he said that because something else B said before.

I would rather say it is a discussion, or a debate. I noticed that an American friend of mine would tend to use *fighting* for such cases.

Is *fighting* the right word? Can the word be used when two people are exchanging instant messages with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *fighting* (gerund or continuous verb) or *a fight* (noun) to mean a verbal argument, especially between friends, family members, or romantic partners.  It is a little bit casual, but extremely common in spoken English, at least North American English.

The first two expressions Felix has suggested (*heated debate* or *rapid exchange*) would be more appropriate in political, workplace, or similar contexts.  *Rapid exchange* is not a common expression (a Google [search](https://www.google.co.jp/#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22rapid+exchange%22&oq=%22rapid+exchange%22&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.20.20.1.858.1.1.0.0.0.0.184.184.0j1.1.0.les;ernk_timediscountc..0.0...1.1.4.psy-ab.S_kN7bDr_SU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=d954904b54849dc&biw=1080&bih=521) pulls up mostly scientific contexts), so is not so useful.  His third suggestion, *argument* (the noun form of the verb *argue*) could be used in any context, and is more formal than *fight/fighting*.

My above comments would apply to any medium: face-to-face or text message, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You have a choice here:

> **Heated Debate**: where the parties are debating according to proper etiquette but it is clear they are holding back the desire to just hit their opponent.
>
> > As the red rushed to their faces, it was clear this was going be a **heated debate**.
>
> **Rapid Exchange**: where the parties are very quickly exchanging their disagreements in order to try and catch the other off (this can be used in other contexts too)
>
> > The previously calm debate quickly turned into a **rapid exchange** of points and rhetoric, with no time to properly consider their opponent's words.
>
> **Argument**: I didn't know if this was too obvious to list or not, but this is where the two parties clearly disagree with eachother and try to overpower the other with their words.
>
> > It became clear that this was no longer a civil discussion, this was a full blown **argument**.